# Меняется ли регистрационный ключ в Google Cloud Messaging?

Tags: android

Использую GCM (Google Cloud Messaging)
Так не могу найти ответа. Меняется ли регистрационный айди или нет? и сколько он действителен времени, если меняется?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Он может меняться.
Приложению нужно обязательно перерегистрироваться на сервере GCM в двух случаях:

1. При смене версии приложения
2. При восстановлении приложения из бэкапов.

Возможно, сейчас Google чаще выдает старые ID, но никто им не мешает изменить поведение.
Эти случаи описаны в [документации](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#reg-state).